# angularjs - multiple datas component in single ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

Is it possible to have a `ng-model` with multiple datas? something like:

```
<select ng-model="data1,data2" ng-change="changedValue(data1,data2)"
```

If not how do people normally solve this issue?

Comment: how can you have multiple ng-model in single component ?

Comment: That is actually my question. Can I have multiple `ng-model` in single component? if not is there an alternative?

Comment: I don't know yet if it is possible . but why would you need that ?

Comment: If you use `multiple="true"` (to allow multiple selections) your model will be an array anyway and you won't need multiple models. Or are you in fact talking about `ng-options` with multiple data-sources? Then you are better off combining the sources before feeding them to ng-options.

Answer (score 0):

passing multiple values inside model is not valid.

you can do something like this

```
<select multiple="true" ng-model="selectedModel" ng-change="sendData(selectedModel)">
  <option value="1"> first</option>
        <option value="2"> second</option>

  <option value="3"> third</option>

</select>
```

where selectedModel contains array of selected options

Comment: I know how to do this and this is not what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

**Use ng-list**

```
<input name="namesInput" ng-model="names" ng-list required></label>
```

Angular docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngList

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview